# What happens to the return value if I don't store it anywhere?

Tags: c++

In the small sample below:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int z(){
    return 5 + 10; // returns 15
}

int main(){
    z(); // what happens to this return?
    cout << "Did not fail";
    return 0;
}
```

What happens to the 15? I tried running it in debugger but I can't find it anywhere. I assume that because it didn't get assigned to anything it just vanished but I feel like that's wrong.

I asked my TA about this today and he told me it's stored on the call stack but when I viewed it in debugger I see that it is not.

Comment: It vanishes. How _exactly_ that happens depends on call conventions. Say, some of them pass return value in one of registers (and then you can see it there), some pass it via stack (and the caller just drops this value). Moreover, optimizer can play here as well: it may inline the function and drop the useless calculation. You may want to look at assembly code to see what exactly is happening.

Comment: @yeputons Thanks! So my assumption was correct. Guess I got some more research to do now.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The C++ standard imposes the "as-if" rule. That rule means that a C++ compiler can do anything to a program as long as all side effects (inputs and outputs that are visible to the rest of the system, like writing to a file or showing stuff on the screen) are respected. Going back to my [cheeky philosophical comment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_a_tree_falls_in_a_forest), this means that in C++, when a tree falls in the forest and no one is there to hear it, it doesn't *have* to make a sound (but it can).

In the case of your program, at a high level, since your function does nothing, the compiler may or may not create a call to it, or could even remove it from the compiled binary. If it does include and call it, the return value will go to whatever return slot your platform's application binary interface specifies. On almost every x86_64 system, that will be the `rax` register for an integer return value. The return value is there but will never be read and will be overwritten at some point.

If it was a non-trivial object instead of an `int`, its destructor would be invoked immediately.

Comment: For reference, all of `icc`, `clang`, and `gcc` still _include_ `z()` in the [compiled binary](https://godbolt.org/g/ZPa39l), but none of them actually call it. Perhaps this is because compilers can't generally exclude symbols which aren't necessarily local to the compilation unit (I suppose you could somehow link against or dynamically load it). If you declare `z()` as `static`, [all of the above omit it entirely](https://godbolt.org/g/3Fa2MH). When the compiler can't see the body of `z()` the function is still called, but the return value `eax` [is ignored](https://godbolt.org/g/w72NWM).

Comment: @BeeOnRope Would the compiler still not call the function if something else besides instanly returning from z() was done? For example an assignment to a variable in the heap...

Answer (score 9):

In general: when a function returns a non-`void` value and the value does not get stored anywhere, the value is destroyed.

Specifically: natural datatypes, like `int`s and `double`s, or pointers, don't have an explicit destructor, so nothing really happens. The returned value simply gets ignored.

If a function returns a class instance, the class instance gets destroyed, which results in an invocation of the class's defined destructor, or a default destructor.